# js: accessing scope of a closure

Tags: javascript, object, closures

I have an object `SomeObject = {property: function}` where "*property*" is `function() { anotherFunction() }`. 
Is there any way to get content and scope of "*anotherFunction*" closure?

Getting this object 'as is' and need to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint on it (or insert a `debugger;` statement just before it) and then run the code and examine the stack and context in a debugger.

[image: Debugger screenshot]

Comment: Is there a way to get it using javascript?

Comment: Have no access to debugger, everything happens in online editor [link] (http://codewars.com) with the intention to make things complex